# Ruby no such file to load

Tags: ruby, rubygems, httparty

I'm trying to use httparty

```
require 'httparty'
```

but I'm getting

```
no such file to load -- httparty (LoadError)
```

I'm using Ruby 1.8.7 on OSX

Comment: Did you do `gem install httparty`? If you did, are you using Bundler? If so, did you include the gem in your Gemfile?

Comment: I did `code`(gem instal httparty), but I'm not using bundler. I think the issue was that I wasn't requiring rubygems... Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

On Ruby 1.8, you have to do `require "rubygems"` before you can require any Gems in your code. So:

```
require "rubygems"
require "httparty"

# Your code here.
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, solved my problem... should update to 1.9x but having issues with installing rvm.